# Not able to convert Business Account to Partner Account

Tags: community, partner-communities

I am not able to see the button "Manage External Account" on my Account page in my own Developer Org. Is there any **Feature** or **Permission** that needs to be enabled for this.

Basically, I want to do this in order to assign the Contact (partner User) to Communities.
Also, Communities are not yet enabled in my org.

Thanks !

Chirag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable Communities inside setup before this option appears.

This guide all all the details:  http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

1. Ensure that your organization has Communities licenses. From Setup, click Company Profile > Company Information
2. From Setup, click Customize > Communities > Settings.
3. Select Enable Communities.
4. Select a domain name to use for your communities
5. Click Save

If you have an older DE org this may not be available to you, you should register a new DE org and turn it on there.